# VBA: Automatically hide column when value in range is too small

Tags: excel, vba

I have a timeline, my goal is to automatically hide the columns not needed if the value in the timeline is smaller than PredevStart

In this scenario PredevStart = - 11, so all the columns that have a value of smaller than -11 in the timeline need to be hidden.

I prepared a sub below, which produces a 1004 error in row 4 - where is my mistake?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Hide_DevCol()

    Dim i, PredevStart As Long
    
    For i = 11 To 100
    
    If Worksheets("Projections").Cells(14, i).Value < Range(PredevStart).Value Then
    Worksheets("Projections").columns(i).Hidden = True
    
    End If
    
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `PredevStart` (an unassigned `Long`) is not a valid address for `Range`. Guessing you just wanted `< PredevStart`.

Comment: `If Worksheets("Projections").Cells(14, i).Value < PredevStart Then`